# How to override the blank theme by default.xml?

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, default

I tried to override the app/design/frontend/Vendor/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml, but it doesn't show any changes. 
I want to add custom links in top.links of parent theme (blank theme):

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="contact-us">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Contact Us</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">contact-us</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Like here: http://www.webmull.com/how-to-add-custom-top-links-in-magento-2-header/

I've flushed the cache, but it doesn't show any custom link.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 3):

there is one minor mistakes in your code

```
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="contact-us">
```

Replace your block name **"Contact-us"** to **"contactus.link"**

below is the correct code please review

**for extended Blank Theme**

app/design/frontend/Amydus/test/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <!--  you can easly add New links with following code -->
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
               <!-- Contact us Link -->
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="contactus.link" after="register-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">Constact Us</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">contact-us</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```