# magento 2.1.8 move navigation menu to the left sidebar

Tags: magento-2.1, navigation, sidebar

I have magento 2.1.8 and i tried to move navigation menu to the left sidebar with many different ways I found around here and on other forums but no luck so far.
this is what i currently have on the default.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
 <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="sidebar.main" />
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo.png</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">320</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">133</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

how can i do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your OP is missing the content of your file. I don't have the reputation to leave a comment, so had to post this as an answer :/

Comment: what is OP? sorry i am new to magento

Comment: Your Original Post, it was missing the line of code from your default.xml file when I first looked at the question, it appears to have it now.

Comment: Try this, `<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="sidebar.main" />`, taken from the answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143412/moving-topnav-to-sidebar-in-magento-2

Comment: oh silly me, sorry! thank you for your reply. I did that but it's not working. I have updated the code to the OP as it is now. I don't get it why it does pick up any move commend at all....

Comment: Have you tried flushing the cache after making the changes? The layout changes will most likely not take effect until you've cleared the cache. Also, is this the default.xml for the blank theme, or for an applied theme that you have? The changes may need to go into your used themes default.xml to overwrite any changes it may be setting to the blank theme.

Comment: yes but no luck. theme is a custom one based on the luma blank.

Comment: Just for the sake of thoroughness, you do have the 2-column layout option selected for the design? Default is the 1 column.

Comment: yes it is selected. for some reason whatever i do to the default.xml file it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I saw this 
[How to override the blank theme by default.xml?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105614/how-to-override-the-blank-theme-by-default-xml)

and I realized that I had the `default.xml` file to the wrong folder!!!

this is the right one:

```
app/design/frontend/Amydus/test/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```